# Implement pinch zoom using one touch react native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-gesture-handler

I want to achieve the pinch gesture (zoom) using single Touch of finger in the react native.
![Having four arrow at side of the images. Need to implement the pinch zoom using single touch][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykqSb.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use react-native-gesture-handler to implement this. I simply write some code. Firstly longly press the corner will show the indicator to drag, then drag will change the scale of the image. I don't complete all the functions but just show you some logic. Maybe you should complete by yourself!

https://snack.expo.io/@gwl002/onetouchzoom

A expo snack for the same code

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Alert, Animated } from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { TapGestureHandler, PanGestureHandler, LongPressGestureHandler, State } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export default function App() {
  const [dirButton, setDirButton] = useState(null);
  const imgLongPress = useRef();
  const imgPan = useRef();
  const scaleAnim = new Animated.Value(1);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <LongPressGestureHandler
        ref={imgLongPress}
        simultaneousHandlers={imgPan}
        onHandlerStateChange={({ nativeEvent }) => {
          if (nativeEvent.state === State.ACTIVE) {
            let { x, y } = nativeEvent;
            let buttonPosition = "";
            console.log(x, y);
            if (x < 30 && y < 30) {
              buttonPosition = "topLeft";
            } else if (x > 370 && y < 30) {
              buttonPosition = "topRight";
            } else if (x < 30 && y > 370) {
              buttonPosition = "bottomLeft";
            } else if (x > 370 && y > 370) {
              buttonPosition = "bottomRight";
            } else {
              buttonPosition = null
            }
            setDirButton(buttonPosition)
          }
        }}
        minDurationMs={800}
      >
        <PanGestureHandler
          ref={imgPan}
          simultaneousHandlers={imgLongPress}
          onGestureEvent={({ nativeEvent }) => {
            if (dirButton) {
              console.log(nativeEvent)
              let { x, y } = nativeEvent;
              if (dirButton === "topRight" || dirButton === "bottomRight") {
                scaleAnim.setValue(x / 400)
              } else if (dirButton === "topLeft" || dirButton === "bottomLeft") {
                scaleAnim.setValue((400 - x) / 400)
              }
            }
          }}
        >
          <View style={styles.wrapper}>
            <Animated.Image
              source={require("./assets/test.png")}
              style={[
                { width: 400, height: 400 },
                {
                  transform: [
                    { scale: scaleAnim }
                  ]
                }
              ]}
            />
            <View
              style={[styles.indicator, dirButton ? styles[dirButton] : { width: 0, height: 0 }]}
            >

            </View>
          </View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
      </LongPressGestureHandler>

    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 100,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  wrapper: {
    position: "relative",
  },
  indicator: {
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    position: "absolute"
  },
  topLeft: {
    left: 0,
    top: 0
  },
  topRight: {
    right: 0,
    top: 0
  },
  bottomLeft: {
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  bottomRight: {
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0
  }
});
```

[image: long press the left top corner and then drag to zoom]

Comment: able to run the demo but not able to do scaling. could you please help me with that

Comment: Try long-press the left top corner, will it show the blue indicator?

Comment: But there is one issue which I am also facing same, that whenever you tried to zoom after the first time it will do first zoom in/ zoom out which causes issue

Comment: Maybe you should paste your code. It's hard to know your real problem.